# Gnome Terminal unreliable on tab switch

Tags: gnome-terminal

I use GNOME-Terminal 3.20.2 on GNOME Shell 3.20.4 on SUSE Linux and the hotkeys to switch tabs (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>) only work sporadically. How can I find out the reason for this behaviour and fix it?

Comment: At least on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04, those hotkeys always work for me (what doesn't work is CTRL + Tab to switch between the tabs). Is it maybe an issue related to SUSE?